# Deploy Angular 8 Heroku

Tags: angular, deploy, heroku, angular-8

Estou a realizar o Deploy de uma aplicação em Angular8, porem parece que o Angular não esta sendo construindo nesse processo. É possível inspecionar o código no navegador, porem nada é renderizado. Segue abaixo as configurações e os logs da Heroku:

```
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild

       > chat-bot@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_4d098a2e09d8365e718fcb24180e2544
       > npm run build:prod


       > chat-bot@0.0.0 build:prod /tmp/build_4d098a2e09d8365e718fcb24180e2544
       > ng build --prod
    -----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 41.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v13
       https://capitu.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

O meu package.json possui a seguinte configuração:

```js
{
  "name": "chat-bot",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build:prod"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v10.16.3",
    "npm": "5.8.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "api-ai-javascript": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

E por fim o server.js esta configurado no formato abaixo para rodar a aplicação angular:

```js
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the angularapp directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {

res.render(__dirname + '/index.html')
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Segue abaixo o link da aplicação na Heroku:
https://capitu.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Se vc rodar o ng build --prod ele gera o dist normalmemente?

Comment: Sim eu entrei no CLI da Heroku e a dist esta gerada normalmente....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguem passe pelo mesmo erro as configurações da package.json estão corretas.
Deve-se apenas apontar os arquivos estáticos do node.js para a dist compilada do Angular 
ficando com a seguinte configuração o server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the angularapp directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/chatBot'));

app.get('/', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/chatBot/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Caso tenha duvidas da configuração da dist no terminal dentro da pasta do projeto basta apenas rodar o comando:

```
heroku run bash
```

E ver as configurações

Answer (score 0):

Eu comparei com o meu sistema e tem uma coisas diferentes.

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node server.js",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"},
```

E as dependências do "devDependencies", tem que ficar dentro da chave "dependencies",

Feito essas configurações meu deploy subiu corretamente.

Comment: Seria possivel postar o seu .json completo se fosse possível para que eu possa analisar